# Config gauge series highchart

Tags: highcharts

I have tried config gauge highchart like

[image: this]

This is my code [jsfiddle code](https://jsfiddle.net/ttthhhcg/2Ltenh7v/2/)

```
chart: {
    type: 'gauge',
    plotBackgroundColor: null,
    plotBackgroundImage: null,
    plotBorderWidth: 0,
    plotShadow: false
}
```

I want to make larger for width of circle, change the color of line.

Please help me, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `thickness` property of each `plotBand`

```
 plotBands: [{
        thickness: 50,
            from: 0,
            to: 120,
            color: '#55BF3B' // green
        }, {
        thickness: 50,
            from: 120,
            to: 160,
            color: '#DDDF0D' // yellow
        }, {
        thickness: 50,
            from: 160,
            to: 200,
            color: '#DF5353' // red
        }]
```

And to change the color of line use dial option to your series

```
series: [{
        name: 'Speed',
            dial: {
                    backgroundColor:'#D9972E',
                    radius: '100%',
                    baseWidth: 5,
                        baseLength: '5%',
                        baseWidth: 10,
                        rearLength: '0%',
                },
        data: [80],
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: ' km/h'
        }
    }]
```

https://jsfiddle.net/viethien/8q56hmz2/17/